# Parent/child context for embedded jetty

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I wish to have the context of servlets which exist in my embedded jetty instance to have a parent context of root application context created in the application entry point `static main()`.

Here is the **entry point static main() code**:

```
try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("maincontext.xml")) {

    // Setup lots of things here like database connection

    JServer server = context.getBean(JServer.class);
    server.start(); // Start the embedded jetty server and join()
}
```

This is the **JServer.start() code**:

```
server = new Server(8080);        
server.setHandler(new WebAppContext("./webapp", "/"));
server.start();
server.join();
```

Here is the **web.xml**:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>App</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/jettycontext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Here is the root context **maincontext.xml**:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.package">
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.package\.webapp\.*" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Here is the dispatcher servlet **jettycontext.xml**:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.package.webapp" />    
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

I want to database connection that exists in the root maincontext.xml to be accessible from the servlet context jettycontext.xml, so a parent child relationship.

My gut feeling is that I need to extend the Dispatcher Servlet to handle this myself but I am not sure if that is the best way.

Comment: Whatever you have in `maincontext.xml`, can you take out of it those parts that you want to have common to all servlets but keep in it only the JServer part? Meaning, `maincontext.xml` should only contain JServer and in another xml to put the common beans for all your servlets. Is this possible in your scenario?

Comment: @AndreiStefan - no its not possible. This is definitely possible programatically, however, it would be nice if it could be "configured" via XML.

Comment: Is this a Servlet 3 app? Meaning, is there any way the DispatcherServlet initialization is done outside web.xml?